# Base gluability axiom

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Vakil's "the rising sea" book, the base gluability axiom is defined as:

"(Let $F$ be a sheaf on base {$B_i$}) If $B = \cup B_i$, and we have $f_i \in F(B_i)$ such that $f_i$ agrees with $f_j$ on any basic open set contained in $B_i \cap B_j$ (i.e.,$res_{B_i,B_k}f_i = res_{B_j,B_k}f_j$ for all $B_k \subset B_i \cap B_j$) then there exists $f \in F(B)$ such that $res_{B,B_i}f = f_i$ for all i."

Why the base gluability axiom require the condition "for any basic open set contained in $B_i \cap B_j$" but not "it exists one basic open set contained in $B_i \cap B_j$"?

What if we replace "any" by "one"?

Notice that we only use the "one" condition to prove the extension problem of base sheaf, rather the "any" condition.

Comment: It is a good idea to think about sheaves of functions. What conditions should functions $f_i$ on $B_i$ satisfy so that you can glue them to a function $f$ on $\bigcup_i B_i$?

Comment: @Nico thank you. You are being very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we replace for "any" by "one", then there will be situations where the data $(B_i,f_i)$ satisfies the condition even though you can not glue them.

E.g. consider the topological space $\mathbb R$ which its standard topology. That topology has a basis consisting of open intervals. Let $F$ be the presheaf of functions on $\mathbb R$. This means that for each open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R$ the set $F(U)$ is the set of all set-theoretic functions $U\to \mathbb R$. Consider $B_1 = (-\infty,1)$ and $B_2=(-1,+\infty)$. Then $B = B_1\cup B_2 = \mathbb R$. Let $f_1$ be the function $f_1\in F(B_1)$ which is zero everywhere, except at the origin where $f_1(0) = 1$. Let $f_2\in F(B_2)$ be the function which is zero everywhere, except at the origin, where $f_2(0) = -1$.

Now $f_1$ and $f_2$ agree on some basic open subset contained in $B_1\cap B_2 = (-1,1)$, for example on $(0,1)$, but not on all of them. You also see that $f_1$ and $f_2$ can not possibly be glued to a function $f$ on $B_1\cup B_2$. So with your definition the presheaf $F$ would not be a sheaf.